# horizontal recyclerview has item cardview bottom textview part not fully displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, horizontal-scrolling

Trying to use horizontal recycleview for carousel behavior, but in landscape mode the item is not displayed right.

The same behavior could be seen by using the project at https://github.com/AndroidCodility/HorizontalRecyclerview  (and a few other github examples)

[image]

in landscape

[image]

Borrow the code for showing the issue here (credit goes to Govind).

the code is straight forward and simple:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (Utility.isOnline(this)) {
            displayList()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun displayList() {
        val version = ArrayList<Version>()
        version.addAll(Version.getList())
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(version)
    }
}
```

and the adapter:

```
/**
 * Created by Govind on 3/7/2018.
 */
class MyAdapter(private val versionList: ArrayList<Version>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(versionList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return versionList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindItems(version: Version) {
            val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
            val imageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
            textView.text = version.name

            Glide.with(itemView.context).load(version.url).into(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

main layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.codility.horizontalrecyclerview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/applicant_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/about"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

card item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of your **`LinearLayout`** to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your **card item layout**

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.codility.horizontalrecyclerview.MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/applicant_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: after the change it is still the same, the textview is not fully displayed.

Comment: @lannyf may be issue with your `main layout:` check updated answer

Comment: using your updated main layout (without change the item layout) worked. thanks!